# fgets instructions gets skipped.Why?

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

Whenever I do a scanf before a fgets the fgets instruction gets skipped. I have come accross this issue in C++ and I remember I had to had some instrcution that would clear the stdin buffer or something like that. I suppose there's an equivalent for C. What is it?

Thanks.

Comment: Code, please .. ?

Comment: You might find it easier to use `fgets` for all your input and then use `sscanf` when you want to parse values from a line.

Comment: @Tim Post: I thought this would be so straitforward for most of the users, that didn't find it necessary. I think the question is detailed enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll bet it's because of the \n stuck in the input stream.

See one of these questions:

[I am not able to flush stdin.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187474/i-am-not-able-to-flush-stdin)
[How do I go about Flushing STDIN here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598131/how-do-i-go-about-flushing-stdin-here)
[scanf() causing infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013/scanf-causing-infinite-loop)

or [this answer](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html).

Also: [Why not to use scanf()](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

P.S. `fgets()` is a function, not an instruction.

Answer (score 3):

The `fgets()` function following the call to `scanf()` is *probably*<sup>1</sup> not getting skipped.  It is *probably*<sup>1</sup> returning immediately having found a newline in the input stream.

Calling `scanf()` before `fgets()` almost always results in `scanf()` leaving an unused newline (`'\n'`) in the input stream, which is exactly what `fgets()` is looking out for.

In order to mix `scanf()` and `fgets()`, you need to remove the newline left behind by the call to `scanf()` from the input stream.

One solution for flushing stdin (including the newline) would be something along the lines of the following:

```
int c;
/* discard all characters up to and including newline */
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

<sub>1 - It is difficult to be certain without seeing the actual code.</sub>

---

Or, as [Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179910/jerry-coffin) suggested in his comment below, you could use `scanf("%*[^\n]");`.  The `"%*[^\n]"` directive instructs `scanf()` to match things that are not newlines and suppress assignment of the result of the conversion.

```
/* match up to newline */
scanf("%*[^\n]"); 
/* discard the newline */
scanf("%*c");
```

From http://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush1.html:

> An initial `scanf()` with `“%*[^\n]”` will either eat everything up to but not including a newline, or fail. A subsequent `“%*c”` (or plain old `getchar()`) will consume the newline, if there was one.
>
> That last “if” matters too: perhaps the user signalled EOF. In this case, the `getchar()` or `scanf("%*c")` might -- this decision is left to the people who write your compiler -- either immediately return EOF, or go back to the user for more input. If the implementors choose the latter, the user might have to click on “end this thing” (^D, ^Z, mouse button, front panel switch, or whatever) one extra time. This is annoying, if nothing else.

---

Or, as [Chris Dodd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16406/chris-dodd) suggested in his comment below, you could use `scanf("%*[^\n]%*1[\n]");`.  The `"%*[^\n]%*1[\n]"` directive instructs `scanf()` to match things that are not newlines and then match one newline and suppress assignment of the results of the conversion.

```
/* match and discard all characters up to and including newline */
scanf("%*[^\n]%*1[\n]");
```

Comment: You can flush the input buffer (i.e., discard until newline is reached) a little more easily with: `scanf("%*[^\n]");`

Comment: You can flush up to and including the newline with `scanf("%*[^\n]%*1[\n]")`

Answer (score 1):

You can just put this line before your `fgets()` call and that'll get the trailing `'\n'` generated when you pressed `enter`

```
scanf("%c", (char *) stdin);
```