# C: fgets skips user input

Tags: c, input, fgets

I'm trying to use fgets to obtain user input from the command line. The code snippet is part of a function that allows users to add new nodes to a singly linked list. As you can see from my code, I use a while loop to keep requesting input from the user (so that he/she can add more than one node). When I run the program, everything is fine the first time. When I try to add a second node, however, the program skips the input request for the first name field. In my command line, I get First name: Last name:

```
while (go)
{
    char first_name[256];
    char last_name[256];
    char telephone[256];
    char address[256];

    printf("First name: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(first_name, sizeof(first_name), stdin);
    //scanf("%s", &first_name);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Last name: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(last_name, sizeof(last_name), stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    //scanf("%s", &last_name);

    printf("Address: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(address, sizeof(address), stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    //scanf("%s", &address);

    printf("Telephone: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(telephone, sizeof(telephone), stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    //scanf("%s", &telephone);

    if (!search_by_all(first_name, last_name, address, telephone))
    {
        add_entry(first_name, last_name, address, telephone);
        printf("Success adding entry! Add another entry? 1 for yes, 0 for no.\n");
        scanf("%d", &go);
        fflush(stdin);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error adding entry. Quitting...\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

I have looked at similar questions on stackoverflow and other sites, but flushing stdin and stdout don't do the trick for me. Neither does allocating more space in my buffers. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Why `fflush(stdin)` ? Isn't that undefined behaviour, at least on most platforms?

Comment: don't use `fflush(stdin);` if you are not using Microsoft compiler

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why fgets is not inputting first value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092468/why-fgets-is-not-inputting-first-value)

Comment: I used fflush because I saw that as a suggestion to resolve a similar problem. But I should avoid it?

Comment: This is probably third post today with the same problem. You `scanf` does not read the newline which you've typed when entering `go`. The newline is then read by the next fgets as an empty line and confusing your program. Add a space after `%d`, i.e. `scanf("%d ", &go);`

Comment: Hi Marian, your solution did not work for me.

Comment: @Marian The suggested `scanf("%d ", &go);` does not work because `scanf()` will not return until some non-white-space is entered after the `int` such as `"123\nX"`.  This non-white-space read by `scanf()` terminates the `' '` directive that you are advocating.  `scanf()` then puts this non-white-space back into `stdin` for the next I/O operation.  Further, `stdin` is typically buffered, so the `'X'` is not seen until a `'\n'` follows it obliging the user to enter `"123\nX\n"`.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &go);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &go);` : `%*c` read and drop `'\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()` is problematic.

Suggest all `fgets()` and check results.

```
// scanf("%d", &go);
char buf[sizeof(go)*3 + 3];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF();
if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &go) != 1) Handle_BadInput;
```

---

The typical usage of `scanf()` leaves the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `'\n'` in `stdin`.  A subsequent call to `fgets()` then returns *only* `"\n"`.

Note: Confident all occurrences of `fflush(stdin);` may be removed.