# looping error ,program stop and show "INPUT NOT VALID!!" but ask again for input?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, do-while

I have these two problems:

1. I have this code which will take number of hours. If `total_hours` is greater than 60, then it should stop. It does stop, but then it shows the message`INPUT NOT VALID!!` and asks for input again (which it should not.)
2. Otherwise, is true the first input called "name" is not asked in the second time  "when use put "Y" as an answer ".

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    int total_hours;
    char name[100], category[3], nic[140];
    float gross_pay, overtime_pay, net_pay;
    int straight_time = 44, pay_hour;
    char con;

    do {
        fgets(name, 100, stdin);

        printf("NIC:");
        fgets(nic, 140, stdin);

        printf("Category:");
        fgets(category, 3, stdin);

        printf("Total Hours:");
        scanf("%d", & total_hours);

        printf("\n\t\t  Smart Store Hypermarket \n");
        printf("============================================================\n");
        printf("Name:%s\nNIC:%s\nCategory:%s\nTotal Hours:%d\n\n", name, nic, category, total_hours);

        if (strncmp(category, "A1", 2) == 0) {
            pay_hour = 5;
        } else if (strncmp(category, "A2", 2) == 0) {
            pay_hour = 7;
        } else if (strncmp(category, "M1", 2) == 0) {
            pay_hour = 10;
        } else if (strncmp(category, "M2", 2) == 0) {
            pay_hour = 15;
        } else if (strncmp(category, "BB", 2) == 0) {
            pay_hour = 20;
        }

        if (total_hours > 44 && total_hours < 60) {
            gross_pay = straight_time * pay_hour;
            overtime_pay = pay_hour;
            net_pay = gross_pay + pay_hour;
            printf("Gross pay = %.2f RM\nOvertime pay =%.2f RM\nNet pay= %.2f RM\n", gross_pay, overtime_pay, net_pay);
            printf("\nContinue (Y/N) ? :");
            scanf("\n%c", &con);

        } else {
            printf("INPUT NOT VALID!!");
        }

    } while ((con != 'N'));
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: How do you want it to stop?  Put a `return` in the `else` clause and it will `return` to the OS.

Comment: if user input a number in total_hours like 90 it should stop and show the message "INPUT NOT VALID!! "quit the program .not to ask user for more input

Comment: Put `return -1` or something like that right after `printf("INPUT NOT VALID!!");` and it will do that.

Comment: break did the trick ,how about why the second time "when use put "Y" as an answer ".can not input "name " but the others work fine

Comment: Do you mean, `return` did the trick?  `break` would work too but it would return nothing to the OS, which is something bad (i.e. undefined behavior).

Comment: yes return worked very well

Comment: See my answer… There's more stuff in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `break` statement after the line `printf("INPUT NOT VALID!!");` to exit the loop instead of repeating it.

As for your other issue, Running `fgets` after a `scanf` can cause it to receive an empty line. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907062/fgets-instructions-gets-skipped-why) for the reason and solutions.

Comment: yes break  did the trick ,how about why the second time "when use put "Y" as an answer ".can not input "name " but the others work fine .

Comment: That's what I explained in the second paragraph, it's due to mixing `fgets` and `scanf`.

Comment: what can we do about it ?!

Comment: Did you read the linked question? It contains several solutions, for example putting `while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); ` after the `scanf`.