# fgets to get "string" from input (keyboard) in C

Tags: c, fgets

In my program doesn't use scanf , I replaced it with fgets,but i've some problems.
My scope: have a function that return a char* to a "string",but if is "\n" or " " (space) in the first character it will print an error,and repeat the input.

I wrote this:

```
#define DIM_INPUT 20
char buffer[DIM_INPUT]; 

char* readFromInput(){
size_t length = 0;
int cycle = 1;
if(length < 3){
    while(cycle){
        fgets(buffer,DIM_INPUT,stdin);
        length = strlen(buffer);
        char first = buffer[0];
        char* c = &first;
        if(strcmp(c,"\n") == 0){
            printf("Error,repeat\n");
            cycle = 1;
        }
        else if(strcmp(c," ") == 0){
            printf("Error,repeat\n");
            cycle = 1;
        }
        else
            return c;
    }
}
else{
    if(buffer[length-1] == '\n'){
        buffer[length-1] = 0;
    }
    char* input = malloc(sizeof(char)*length);
    strcpy(input,buffer);
    if(strlen(buffer)==DIM_INPUT-1) //
        CLEAN_STDIN;
    memset(buffer,'\0',sizeof(buffer)); 
    return input;
}
```

}

And CLEAN_STDIN is a macro to consume additional characters:

```
{ int ch;while((ch = fgetc(stdin))!='\n'  && ch != EOF  );}
```

The problem is when using it has some strange problems , especially when I enter in input one character.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fgets instructions gets skipped.Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907062/fgets-instructions-gets-skipped-why)

Comment: DO NOT do `strcmp(c,"\n")`, which should be undefined behavior. You should compare them in straight way: `c == '\n'`. Also don't do `strcmp(c," ")`, either.

Comment: returning `c` in this codemakes no sense because `c` points `first`, which is non-static local variable and will vanish on returning.

Comment: To begin with, what is "string" here?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strcmp(c,"\n") == 0){
```

Undefined behaviour. Try:

```
if(c == '\n'){
```

Similarly for the second instance of it.

Comment: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
    else if(c == ' '){

for your solution,I must replace c with first,beacuse "first" is the first char of buffer. c is char* of it.

Comment: @minimanimo Either substitute `c` with `first` or add an asterisk before `c`.